# trim option of \animategraphics fails

Tags: animate, crop

When I try to crop images (see code below) with animategraphics, the animation works but the image is not cropped. When I run the code with "example-image-duck" instead of my own images the animation is effectively cropped.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Test animation}
    \animategraphics[loop,autoplay,trim = 0 1cm 0 0,width=\linewidth]{1.0}{image-}{0}{4}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I also tested with PNG versions of the example image files. Everything works ok here. Do you still experience the problem? Could you make those files available for download? (Perhaps on the issues page of `animate`: https://gitlab.com/agrahn/animate/issues .)

Comment: Sorry, I have been offline these days. I will try again on my side and  let you know.

Comment: I have redo the test, it works fine. my bad. So if it is OK I can delete this question.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. You may delete the Q if you wish.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question (with OP's consent) as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

I copy-renamed [`example-image.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mwe/example-image.pdf), [`example-image-a.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mwe/example-image-a.pdf), [`example-image-b.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mwe/example-image-b.pdf), [`example-image-c.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mwe/example-image-c.pdf) from pkg `mwe` as `image-0.pdf`, `image-1.pdf`, `image-2.pdf`, `image-3.pdf` to the current directory. It seems to work as I get

[image]

using different engines (`pdflatex`, `lualatex`, `xelatex`).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Test animation}
    \animategraphics[loop,autoplay,trim = 0 3cm 0 0,width=\linewidth]{1.0}{image-}{0}{3}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```